# Why would an airline put my bag on a different flight?

Tags: luggage, united-airlines

I’m currently on a direct United flight from Newark to Los Angeles. While boarding I got the dreaded “bag is on a different flight” notification. That’s a later flight that will arrive 4 hours after mine. But… why did United do this? My bag was checked in 2 hours before the flight so it’s not like there wasn’t enough time to put it on the plane.

[image]

> We wanted to let you know that your bag will arrive on a later flight. To save time and skip the baggage services line, use the United App to set up complimentary bag delivery.

Comment: This usually happens mostly in 2 reasons either the people in charge of luggage load the wrong barrow or they're aren't enough staff to cover up

Comment: Let's not overlook their transparency (we goofed) and promise to hand-deliver the bag. Owed, but still courteous. Happened to me in Orlando: "Sorry, your bag went to Melbourne." "Please tell me there's a Melbourne, Florida!" "Yes." And they taxied it to my hotel 2 hours later.

Comment: @YosefBaskin the app's promise of being able to schedule delivery was actually a lie. Impossible via the app, chat support told me to go speak to an agent at the airport instead. I ended up just waiting another couple of hours at the airport because I didn't trust United to not mess it up further.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Update: Actual reason for this occurring at the end...**

There's generally two reasons that this could happen.

1. Your bags was "lost" at the origin airport.  When they have finished loading the bags onto the plane, the staff will be aware that your bag isn't on that flight (as they individually scan each bag as it is checked in, and then again when it's loaded) - but they may not know where it is at the time. Perhaps it was accidentally put with the baggage for a different flight, or perhaps it fell off the baggage cart somewhere.  Or maybe the bag was taken aside for inspection by TSA and not returned in sufficient time to make the flight. Or the baggage tag came off it or was damaged so it had to be manually handled to work out where it was going. Or any of a number of other factors that could have occurred.

Obviously we can only guess at the actual cause, but the end result is the same - the airline didn't have the bag to load, and didn't want to delay your flight whilst they waited to find it.

2. Your flight was full!  Just as there's a limit to the amount of people that can fit on a single flight, there's also a limit to the amount of baggage.  That includes not only the baggage for the people on the flight, but also any cargo the airline has to transport.

These limits apply not just in terms of space, but also the overall weight of the aircraft. Weight can especially be a problem on longer flights like this one, where weather conditions can also play a part in terms of how much fuel the plane needs to carry - strong headwinds or a longer route to avoid weather will mean more fuel required, which can mean less cargo/bags can be carried.

In this case the airline has a choice of removing passengers from the flight, or removing luggage and sending it on a later flight - and you can guess which option they will normally take!

Whatever the cause, the airline was obviously able to find the bag and put it on a later flight.  They will arrange for it to be delivered to wherever you are staying, so hopefully the impact isn't too great!

**Edited to add :**

It seems the cause of the delay was [issues](https://twitter.com/EWRairport/status/1768981648308404636) with the baggage systems at EWR that occurred this morning. These problems are causing delays at check-in, causing some flights to be delayed whilst they attempt to get the bags to the flights, and in some cases are causing flights to depart without all of their intended bags.  The issues were apparently with the TSA baggage scanning equipment, so not a problem related to United Airlines as such.

Comment: As an aside: this is why one should _always_ travel with a carry-on with essentials! A change of underwear, toothbrush & toothpaste, etc... always plan for 24h without your main luggage, and you'll be way less stressed and much more comfortable if it ever happens.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I pack with a 3 layered system: 1) Never expect to see checked luggage again. 2) Be able to drop your carry on a run when needed. 3) Always carry what is critical for your journey (passport, cash, CCs etc) securely on your person.  But yes, I also pack my carry on with enough to last at least a day.

Comment: Air New Zealand has been facing this issue at times with their new New York City flights from Auckland direct on a 787-9. This flight is at the extreme edge of the 787 rated range, so fuel is a constant concern. If headwinds and load factors are such that the flight needs to be lightened, they will sometimes route luggage via one of their shorter 777 routes like Houston instead.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Don't need a toothbrush or toothpaste, at least in the US. DOT regulations require airlines pay for reasonable incidental expenses due to delayed bags. To minimize their bill, airlines hand out kits that have toothpaste, a toothbrush, sanitizer/wet wipes, comb, razor, and deodorant on request.

Comment: @user71659: I'll take mine, thanks. (1) it's available without delay, (2) it matches my preferences.

Comment: As an example of #2 for cargo, we were once told our bag was removed to make room for spare parts needed to repair a plane at our destination. Sometimes it's a matter of the airline deciding which delays will be more costly in the long run.

Answer (score 8):

While we cannot know why specifically your bag wasn’t loaded on your flight, there a a lot of possibilities:

- Someone just messed up and put your bag in the wrong pile/container, or forgot a container, or took a container to the wrong flight, or any other human error
- A reason which was very frequent recently when airports were not able to ramp up their capacity as quickly as people returned to flying after the pandemic: not enough staff, so they don’t have the people to move the bags around and load them up in planes. Also happens in case of industrial action, or when there was an earlier baggage system disruption and they’re playing catch up. In that case it often affects a lot of the luggage (sometimes full planes). Airlines weigh the pros and cons of waiting for the bags (which will disrupt everyone on the flight, including those with carry ons only, as well as people on the following flights using the same airplane, and connections, etc.) and have to make a decision at some point.
- There was a problem with the luggage sorting system. In many places these systems are very automated to reduce the need for manpower and the risk of human errors (the two points above), but some seem to be extremely sensitive and shut down very often. This can either directly affect your luggage (it’s somewhere in the system but not moving) or have knock on effects as described above.
- Your luggage got stuck in the system (loose straps are the enemy of the conveyor systems). Someone had to go fix the situation.
- Your bag just fell of a cart (when not using containers) or off the conveyor system (possibly as a consequence of it or another bag getting stuck)
- Your bag took too long in security scans.
- The tag was somehow torn off and needed manual handling.
- Your bag still had old tags which confused the system
- There was no capacity for your bag (space or weight). While this is common on smaller airplanes, I would be surprised if it were the case in this specific situation.
- Your bag was somehow damaged and it took some time to process it and wrap it.
- And probably many more…

There is also the possibility that the bag was initially mislabeled, but in that case it would probably take a bit longer for them to notice and correct the situation.

Comment: Another less innocent possibility is that the bag was removed from the proper flow so that stuff could be stolen from it.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like human or technical error. At check-in, your bag could be tagged incorrectly or the tag could come off during movement. Sometimes baggage handlers load the wrong barrows or sometimes there aren’t enough staff to cover the amount of flights at one time.

Or it could be that some baggage had to be sent separately so that the final flight load of your aircraft did not exceed safety limits.